# Finding variance inflation factors for the explanatory variables

Tags: r, database, dataframe, data-science

**This is my fitness.df**

```
##    oxy...age...wt...run..rest.p..run.p.max.p
## 1    44.61  44  89.5  11.37   62   178   182
## 2    45.31  40  75.1  10.07   62   185   185
## 3    54.30  44  85.8   8.65   45   156   168
## 4    59.57  42  68.2   8.17   40   166   172
## 5    49.87  38  89.0   9.22   55   178   180
## 6    44.81  47  77.5  11.63   58   176   176
## 7    45.68  40  76.0  11.95   70   176   180
## 8    49.09  43  81.2  10.85   64   162   170
## 9    39.44  44  81.4  13.08   63   174   176
## 10   60.06  38  81.9   8.63   48   170   186
## 11   50.54  44  73.0  10.13   45   168   168
## 12   37.39  45  87.7  14.03   56   186   192
## 13   44.75  45  66.5  11.12   51   176   176
## 14   47.27  47  79.2  10.60   47   162   164
## 15   51.86  54  83.1  10.33   50   166   170
## 16   49.16  49  81.4   8.95   44   180   185
## 17   40.84  51  69.6  10.95   57   168   172
## 18   46.67  51  77.9  10.00   48   162   168
## 19   46.77  48  91.6  10.25   48   162   164
## 20   50.39  49  73.4  10.08   67   168   168
## 21   39.41  57  73.4  12.63   58   174   176
## 22   46.08  54  79.4  11.17   62   156   165
## 23   45.44  52  76.3   9.63   48   164   166
## 24   54.63  50  70.9   8.92   48   146   155
## 25   45.11  51  67.3  11.08   48   172   172
## 26   39.20  54  91.6  12.88   44   168   172
## 27   45.79  51  73.7  10.47   59   186   188
## 28   50.55  57  59.1   9.93   49   148   155
## 29   48.67  49  76.3   9.40   56   186   188
## 30   47.92  48  61.2  11.50   52   170   176
## 31   47.47  52  82.8  10.50   53   170   172
```

I am trying to find diagonal elements of the inverse of the
correlation matrix for the explanatory variables which is the vifs.

**my r code is here:**

```
round(diag(solve(cor(fitness.df[, 1:7]))), 2)
```

However this gives error saying undefined columns. I am so confused. May I get some help please. TIA.

Comment: could you first try doing `fitness.df[, 1:7]` and see whether there is any error

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for you reply. However I just fixed mine apparently my dataframe wasn't properly structured. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you screwed up the data input. The print output you show has a header looking like:   `oxy...age...wt...run..rest.p..run.p.max.p`. All of those periods suggest to me that you used the wrong data separator and you really only have one giant column that cannot be used.. Voting to claose as a typo. If you need further help:  Show us the actual content of your file and the code you used to import it to R.